# Using a UWP library in a C++ console app

Tags: c++, console, uwp, lib

I understand that this isn't a really common use case, but my team has built a C++ UWP static library and I'd like to link it into an existing C++ console app.  However, I can't find anywhere that says that this is possible, or even anyone that's asked this question.  If I try naively adding a reference, it just says that "the two platforms are incompatible" (I'd imagine one is targeting UWP and the other just targets Windows).

Does anyone know if this is possible?  Would save me a pretty big rewrite.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your library is not portable is not possible.

If you have access code to the code of the UWP library try to port al the code to portable library and try it again.

Best Regards